# Where to get the domain confirmation string certbot?

Tags: linux, certbot

I was following this tutorial:

https://flaviocopes.com/express-letsencrypt-ssl/

> …and finally we get to the verification phase!
>
> Create a file containing just this data:
>
> **TS_oZ2-ji23jrio3j2irj3iroj_U51u1o0x7rrDY2E.1DzOo_voCOsrpddP_2kpoek2opeko2pke-UAPb21sW1c**
>
> And make it available on your web server at this URL:

Where do I get this long string mentioned there? I didn't copy it when I made the certs with certbot but now I need to confirm my domain with such string. Where is it located?

Comment: The string is the output of the process described in the link. It will change every single time you go through this process.  You need to copy it from the command line and create a file containing that (and only that) string

Comment: Yes, but is it also saved somewhere so I can get it later?

Comment: No, it will be in the file you create.  If you didn't copy it, you need to start the process again and get a new string

Comment: If you did not save it, it was not saved for you in a file

Comment: Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is the output of the process described in the link. It will change every single time you go through this process.

You need to copy it from the command line and create a file containing that (and only that) string.

If you didn't copy it, you need to start the process again and get a new string.

Comment: Actually, I think the tutorial might be outdated. I tried to run 'certbot certonly --manual' and certbot certonly --standalone and in neither cases it gives me a string like that. I think you only get that string if you are running certbot with --webroot flag. In other cases it does that confirmation automatically.

Comment: @sander Interesting, maybe you need to remove the cert and add a new one? https://www.clusterednetworks.com/blog/post/common-certbot-commands